# iPad protocol problem

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, ipad

I have a little problem; I have this protocol defined as so below:

```
@protocol someProtocol <NSObject>

- (void) changedStoryForIndexPath: (NSIndexPath *) indexPath;

@end
```

I have it defined in a file named "`ListViewController.h`", logically I have to import the header in another file like: `#import "ListViewController.h"` then in my `@interface` declare the protocol in the protocol tags like `<someProtocol>` right? When do I do so then compile, the compiler (on Xcode 4.0 and 3.2.4) tells me that it can't find the protocol declaration. You can see the error here: http://www.freeimagehosting.net/uploads/5ff0c99bf7.png

Thank You guys!

Comment: It usually just works well. Maybe the problem is somewhere else

Comment: Show your code for where you use it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should have the protocol in a different header file.

SomeProtocol.h:

```
@protocol someProtocol <NSObject>
- (void) changedStoryForIndexPath: (NSIndexPath *) indexPath;
@end
```

And import it in the ListViewController class.

```
#import "SomeProtocol.h"
```

Comment: Thanks @vakio, weird, it's the first time I have to make a separate protocol header. I normally just declare the protocol in a header and voila. Thanks!